# Almacenar datos mientras se pulse una tecla

Tags: array, c

Necesito realizar un código que te pida un numero y lo almacene en un array mientras que se pulse la tecla "f". Y luego sumamos todos los números del array y los almacenamos en una variable int resultado para posteriormente mostrarlo por pantalla. De momento solo tengo puesto este código y no consigo almacenar el dato. Agradecería una ayuda.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int resultado;
    int numeros[2];
    int c;
    int numero;
    
    while ((c=getchar())!= 'f') {
        printf("Introduce un numero: ");
        cin >> numero;
    }
    
    printf("Es: "<< numero);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta aclarar las ideas antes de ponerte a programar. Piensa qué quieres conseguir, qué necesitas, qué pasos hay que dar, etc.

Primero quieres ingresar un número y validar dicho número solicitando que el usuario introduzca la letra `F`, pues tiene lógica que primero pidas el número como dices en tu pregunta y luego confirmes mediante la letra F, y no al revés como tienes en tu código.
Por otro lado, intenta siempre trabajar con macros `#define`, ya que harán mucho más sencilla la modificación y comprensión de tu código. Esto viene bien a la hora de dar un tamaño a tu array. En este caso es siempre recomendable ser generoso antes que quedarse cortos, por lo que si no sabes el tamaño de tu array, dale siempre valores más grandes de lo que creas (siempre vete al caso más restrictivo).

El código que buscas podría parecerse a algo a esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAM 2

int main()
{
    int resultado;
    int numeros[TAM];
    int contador=0, i=0;
    int numero_ingresado;

    char c;

    do {
        printf("Introduce un numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &numero_ingresado);
        printf("Si quieres guardar el numero %d, pulsa F  ", numero_ingresado);
        scanf(" %c", &c);
        if( (c == 'f') || (c == 'F') )
        {
            numeros[contador] = numero_ingresado;
            contador++;
        }
        else
            printf("Ingresion del numero abortada\n");
    } while (contador < TAM);

    for ( i=0 ; i<TAM ; i++)
    {
        resultado+=numeros[i];
    }
    printf("\nEl resultado total es: %d", resultado);

    return 0;
}
```

Fíjate también en el tipo de dato que es la variable `c`. ¿La quieres comparar con un caracter? Pues trátala como tal y emplea el tipo `char` (en este código que te dejo puedes ingresar `f` o `F`, te detectará las dos).
Por último, fíjate en la variable `contador`, la cuál no he puesto que siempre incremente, sino que sólo incremente cuando insertamos un dato validado (presionando
`F`) ya que sino podríamos recorrer el array y salir del programa sin haber insertado un sólo valor válido.

Cuéntame dudas que te surjan y podremos seguir ayudándote ;)

Pd: revisa la diferencias de sintaxis entre C y C++, porque creo que tienes un cacao importante.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad que me lio bastante entre C y C++. Ahora puedo comprender un poco mejor la sintaxis.

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió márcala como correcta para que futuros OPs no hagan preguntas similares ya formuladas

Answer (score 1):

Te aconsejo que al menos compiles el código fuente, ya que es evidente que aún no lo has hecho. No obstante, te propongo que amplies el código para que recoja adecuadamente todos los numeros (hasta un máximo de 200):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int resultado;
    int numeros[200];
    int current; 
    int c;
    int numero;
    
    current = 0;
    printf( "Continuar? (pulsa f para finalizar) " );
    while ((c=getchar())!= 'f') {
        printf("Introduce un numero: ");
        scanf( "%d", &numero );
        printf( "Continuar? (pulsa f para finalizar) " );
        numeros[current++] = numero;
    }
    
    // FALTA: sumar todos los números del array numeros, desde 
    // la posicion 0 hasta current y dejar el resultado en numero

    printf("Es: "<< numero);
    
    return 0;
}
```